Docker environment for a Vite project Errror
When setting up a Docker environment for a Vite project and encountering errors, how do you troubleshoot and resolve them

front@0.0.0 dev  vite  failed to load config from /front/vite.config.js  error when starting dev server:  Error:   You installed esbuild for another platform than the one you're currently using. This won't work because esbuild is written with native code and needs to  install a platform-specific binary executable.   Specifically the "@esbuild/win32-x64" package is present but this platform  needs the "@esbuild/linux-x64" package instead. People often get into this  situation by installing esbuild on Windows or macOS and copying "node_modules"  into a Docker image that runs Linux, or by copying "node_modules" between  Windows and WSL environments.   If you are installing with npm, you can try not copying the "node_modules" directory when you copy the files over, and running "npm ci" or "npm install"  on the destination platform after the copy. Or you could consider using yarn  instead of npm which has built-in support for installing a package on multiple  platforms simultaneously.   If you are installing with yarn, you can try listing both this platform and the other platform in your ".yarnrc.yml" file using the "supportedArchitectures" feature: https://yarnpkg.com/configuration/yarnrc/#supportedArchitectures  Keep in mind that this means multiple copies of esbuild will be present.    Another alternative is to use the "esbuild-wasm" package instead, which works  the same way on all platforms. But it comes with a heavy performance cost and  can sometimes be 10x slower than the "esbuild" package, so you may also not  want to do that.

Dockerfile
FROM node:21.6.2-alpine
WORKDIR /front
COPY package*.json /front/
RUN npm install
COPY . .
EXPOSE 5173
CMD [ "npm","run","dev" ]

Docker Compose
version: '2.1' 
services:   backend:     build: ./back     volumes:       - ./back:/back     ports:       - 9000:9000   front:       build: ./front       volumes:         - ./front:/front         # - /front/node_modules       ports:         - 5173:5173       command: ["npm","run","dev"]   


if i use - /front/node_modules on the volumes the result coming out however this is not update the result is not up to date I want to get update .


Your COPY . . might overwrite node_modules with wrong things?

Delete the volumes: block from the Compose file entirely.  This hides everything in the image, and you can wind up using a wrong-OS node_modules tree, among other problems.  If you want a local live-reloading development environment, just use Node withoug Docker.
